# Does Salesforce OAuth Endpoint work with Expect : 100-continue http header?

Tags: oauth2

Does Salesforce OAuth Endpoint work with Expect : 100-continue http header?  Is it recommended to use this header for OAuth

Answer (score 0):

While I can't comment on whether it is supported or not, I can say that, with fair certainty, there is no documentation anywhere that uses it or recommends it. The Expect header is typically used to abbreviate potentially long requests that are doomed to failure (for example, uploading a 500 MB file when the service limits uploads to 100 MB). At best, using Expect will simply delay the login process.